# javascript regex to match word in lines beginning with double slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to come up with a javascript regex that matches the `new` in this example:

```
// with new operator
```

but not in this example:

```
with the new operator
```

So in any line that begins with // it should match the new but not the double slash.

I am trying to change this regex into what I need but I cant get it right

```
^(?:(?!"$).)([0-9]+)(?!")$
```

How would I do this?

Comment: a = '// with new operator' a.search('//')

Comment: Your sample regular expression has no relevance to you requirements

Comment: well it kinda does. the sample searches numbers not preceded by " and not followed by "... I am looking for strings not preceded by //, arent I?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried something like that?

```
/^\/\/\s*(\w+)/gmi
```

if you want to match the **new** word literally you can do it in this way:

```js
function pickNew(s) {
  var regex = /^\/\/\s*\w+\s*(new)/gmi;
  var result = regex.exec(s);
  
  
  return result && result.pop() || null;
}

console.log(1, pickNew('\/\/ with new operator'));
console.log(2, pickNew('\/\/ with the new operator'));
console.log(3, pickNew('\/\/ withthe new operator'));
```

basically this regex expects two slashes at the beginning, zero or more occurence of whitespaces and a word. Modifiers are: Multiline, Global, CaseInsensitive

Comment: When I test this on this site https://regex101.com/ it matches the "//" and the "with"... I want to match the "new"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search the word new in the sentence that has back slashes, you can use some thing like this which will work.you should escape those backslashes.

```
^\s*\/\/.*[new]
```

Test this reg expression and it will work.